# Python - Different output than expected, directory issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-requests

I'm trying to get to the point where I could possibly have done some mistake in my code as the outcome of my coding is quite unexpected. Whatever input it always returns false.

I think that can be an issue with the directory or index.
I'm providing my code below.

```
def bookASeat(seatID):
    row = seatID[0] # setting the first index of the user input to 0
    column = seatID[1] # the second index of the user input is 1
    #assuming the seatID is correct, find the indexes of the user input in the variable cinemaRows and columnNumber
    while row in cinemaRows and column in columnNumber:
        #usersRows dictionary can be used to check if the SeatID entered is 0, not booked or 1 booked 
        if usersRows[row][column - 1] == 0:
            return True # for not booked
        else:
            return False # for booked
```

Comment: Try adding some parentheses to your while loop. Like `while (row in cinemaRows) and (column in columnNumber):` and see if that fixes it.

Comment: The while loop always executes a `return`, so the loop will only iterate once...

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
while row in range(len(rows)) and column in range(len(columns))
...
if usersRows[row][column] == 0:
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the if else statement by changing the indentation levels a touch just to save a bit of effort:

```
while (row in cinemaRows) and (column in columnNumber):
if usersRows[row][column] == 0:
    return True;
return False;
```